# simple question, need help

Tags: exponentiation

[image: Where does 1 come from on the end?]

Can someone tell me where does 1 come from on the end, this got me really confused.

Comment: $$x^{-n}=\frac{1}{x^n}$$

Comment: By definition $x^{-n} = \frac {1}{x^n}$.  In general $1$ is the *multiplicative identity* which means $1*b = b*1 = b$ for every possible number.  This also means $b/b = 1$ for all non-zero numbers.  In a way, this means 1 is "always there" if we need to notate it.  $b^{x - y} = \frac{b^x}{b^y}$ So for example $b^{2 - 5} = b^2/b^5 = 1/b^3 = b^{-3}$.  This is why we say $b^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^1=3(1)=3$$
$$3^0=1$$
$$3^{-1}=1/3$$
$$3^{-2}=1/9$$

Because 1(x)=x, the 1 is always there no matter whether the exponent is positive, negative, or zero.